# How to draw a line x pips above or below close price in trading view pine script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

How can I create an indicator which is a straight line plus a constant value above it. The idea being that I want to show where my brokers price is compared to the trading view value. So far I've only been able to draw a horizontal line:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Close+Constant", overlay=true)

if barstate.islast
    line.new(bar_index[10], close, bar_index, close, width = 2, color = color.blue,  extend = extend.both)
```

But trying to add a constant float to bar_index[10] (for instance) gives a type error, expected int but got float.

Existing solutions result in the same error:

```
Cannot call 'hline' with argument An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add your spread to the Y value in line :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Close+Constant", overlay=true)
spread = 0.005 // Adjust your spread with the one from your broker
if barstate.islast
    line.new(bar_index[10], close + spread, bar_index, close + spread, width = 2, color = color.blue,  extend = extend.both)
```

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how implement this for only the current price bar? As it stands every new bar gets a new line at `close + constant` and it isn't removed when a new bar is printed.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh No problem, can you ask a new question ? I will answer it with code.

Comment: Sure thing, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75888755/3059024