# Draw line above close in trading view but only for the current candle

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

In a previous question ([How to draw a line x pips above or below close price in trading view pine script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75888365/3059024)) I asked how to draw a line on a trading view graph with pine script. The problem with this is that every new bar results in a new line without deleting the first. So, how can I do the same thing but for only the current price.

// the current script

```
//@version=5
indicator("Close+Constant", overlay=true)
spread = 0.005 // Adjust your spread with the one from your broker
if barstate.islast
    line.new(bar_index[10], close + spread, bar_index, close + spread, width = 2, color = color.blue,  extend = extend.both)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line will always be drawn at each new 'last' bar.
You should - on each last bar - delete your 'old' line then draw it again :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Close+Constant", overlay=true)
spread = 0.005 // Adjust your spread with the one from your broker
var MyLine = line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close+1, color=na) // Declare the line but draw nothing
if barstate.islast
    line.delete(MyLine)
    MyLine = line.new(bar_index[10], close + spread, bar_index, close + spread, width = 2, color = color.blue,  extend = extend.both)
```